# Why does my Samsung Galaxy S3 quit asking for my Screen unlock PIN

Tags: lock-screens

I keep setting up a PIN to unlock my screen. It works a few times, maybe 3 or 4, then stops. My phone reverts to merely having to swipe the screen to unlock it.
I will then again setup a pin to unlock the screen, it will work a few times and then the phone reverts to no PIN required for screen unlock.

Comment: Is it rooted? Stock ROM?